# Get module config in ZF3

Tags: php, model-view-controller, configuration, module, zend-framework3

I'd like to retrieve my module configuration from a controller in Zend Framework 3.
I searched, and it seems that the standard way to do this in ZF2 is to use

```
$this->getServiceLocator()
```

to access the configuration in `module.config.php`.
However, this won't work in ZF3, as there is no `getServiceLocator()` method.

What is the standard way to achieve this?

Comment: There is lot of solution for this.. Can you share your code  so I can better explain ?

Answer (score 5):

Don't know if you found an answer, as there are different solutions as tasmaniski wrote. Just in case, let me share one that would have helped me a lot when I started to play with ZF3:

**MyControllerFactory.php**

```php
<?php
namespace My\Namespace;

use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;
use DependencyNamespace\...\ControllerDependencyClass; // this is not a real one of course!

class MyControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @param ContainerInterface $container
     * @param string $requestedName
     * @param null|array $options
     * @return AuthAdapter
     */
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        // Get config.
        $config = $container->get('configuration');

        // Get what I'm interested in config.
        $myStuff = $config['the-array-i-am-interested-in']

        // Do something with it.
        $controllerDepency = dummyFunction($myStuff);

        /*...the rest of your code here... */

        // Inject dependency.
        return $controllerDepency;
    }
}
```

**MyController.php**

```php
<?php
namespace My\Namespace;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use DependencyNamespace\...\DependencyClass;

class MyController extends AbstractActionController
{
    private $controllerDepency;

    public function __construct(DependencyClass $controllerDepency)
    {
        $this->controllerDepency = $controllerDepency;
    }

    /*...the rest of your class here... */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject your dependencies through service manager. 
Basicly you need to create 2 class  **Controller** and **ControllerFactory** that will create Controller with all dependencies.